# HTTPs Post redirect

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have to transfer information to an external website on click of a button. So, when i click on the button, a new window opens, the existing screen should remain as is. I am using below configuration

```
<action name="ActionName" class="ActionClass"
        method="executeMethod">
        <result name="success">../somejsp</result>
</action>
```

However, whenever i click on the button, the screen gets refreshed and the value on the screen changes. Is there a way we could just prevent this refresh?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to prevent default submit and call the submit from script.
refer: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp for an example.

Whenever we need to do some preprocessing before actual form submit this method allows to do that. This will call a JavaSript function before doing actual submit or if needed prevent form submit.